# Does FAA or EASA has any requirement for Supervised Take off and Landing?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, easa-regulations

India has a regulation of conducting supervised Take off & Landing. Same requires particular experience for Captain and First officer. Is there any similar requirement in FAA or EASA?

Comment: Related: [How common are regulations limiting when the FO can be PF?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20825)

Comment: Can you cite this regulation so we can look up anything comparable in EASA or the FAA FAR's?

Comment: @RonBeyer: It should be [this one](http://dgca.nic.in/aic/aic09_07.pdf), linked in the related question